# how do I update new image on JFrame ? (I tried everything but it didn't work)

Tags: java, swing

so this is my source code, I'm trying to make stick man moving so first, I tried to make head moving. it works, but the problem is that the past movement and the reccentt movement stick together so it goes like this OOOOOOOOOOO when it's supposed to go like this O

I tried repaint() validate() updateUI() but it still didn't work

any idea?

```
    package JamesTestPackage;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

    import javax.swing.*;
    public class StickmanUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{
Timer t = new Timer(1,this);
int x=180;
int x_vel = 0;
int y_vel = 0;
public StickmanUI(){
    t.start();
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));

    g2.drawLine(200, 50, 200, 100); // body

    g2.drawLine(200, 100, 220, 150); // right leg

    g2.drawLine(200, 100, 180, 150); // left leg

    g2.drawLine(200, 75, 170, 100); //left arm

    g2.drawLine(200, 75, 230, 100); //right arm

    g2.drawOval(x, 10, 40, 40); // head


}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    x= x + x_vel;
    repaint();
}
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(arg0.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        x_vel = 1;
    else if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        x_vel = -1;

}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    x_vel =0;
}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing custom painting the first statement in your paintComponent() method should be:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

to make sure the background is cleared before painting is done.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html) for more information and working examples to get your started.

Comment: thanks ! it works now ! but one more question though what does 
super.paintComponent(g); do? I've always seen those but never really understood what it does